# Trouble with numbers using a long decimal

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview

When I run this code on the Android Emulator it shows `2.236328125E-4` instead of `0,00022363224`.

What am I doing wrong?

```
numri=Double.parseDouble(number2.getText().toString());

kalkulimi=(numri* 0.229);

tv.setText(Double.toString(kalkulimi* 0.0009765625));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the way Android (and java in general) internally stores numbers.  If you're after a specific format, I strongly suggest that you use `NumberFormat`:

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0,0##########");
tv.setText(formatter.format(kalkulimi* 0.0009765625));
```

Comment: thanks a lot it threw exception first when i copy-pasted it but then i noticed it wasn't ("0 (dot)0##########");